# One file share part of another file

Tags: command-line

I have a file--A which is created first, then the file--B will be created *depend on* the file A. Then I will

1. cat file A and file B to create file--C;
2. I will write to file C's B part.

**I will repeat the step 1 and step 2.**

```
----------------------------
 A   |    B (write here)    | notice: A, B, C are all binary file
----------------------------
```

Now I wonder if B can share the file C's B part, so I don't need to write to C when I re-create it( i.e. I will skip step 2). The result may like the following:

```
----------------------------
 A   |    link to B        | 
----------------------------
```

**Q:**
So is there any linux command to do so?

Comment: What kind of action do you need to perform on B / C's second part exactly?

Comment: Writing some binary data.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `dd` to write to an offset equal to "A"'s dimension in bytes.

Assuming "C" = 5KB ("A" = 1KB and "B" = 4KB);

To zero out "B":

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=C iflag=fullblock oflag=seek_bytes seek=1000 bs=1000 count=4
```

To substitute "B" with another file "new_B" (if "new_B" is bigger than "B" "C" will grow of a size equal to the difference of "new_B" and "B"):

```
dd if=new_B of=C oflag=seek_bytes seek=1000
```

If the data to be written are the output of another command, another option is to pipe the data directly to `dd`:

```
[...] | dd of=C oflag=seek_bytes seek=1000
```

Comment: I don't quiet get it. If you create "C" by `dd`, then writing to "C" will also change "B"?

Comment: @Tony As per your question, "C" is the result of `cat`ting "A" and "B" (unless I missunderstood something). So "C" "contains" "A" and "B"; "A" is at the start and is immediately followed by "B". Hence writing to "C" skipping "A"-size-bytes (or skipping "A" if you want) will have the effect of writing to "B". Does it make sense?

Comment: It's my fault. See my edit for more clear explanation.